# CC3200 parse.com migration to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, embedded-database

During recent announcement from parse.com; about migration from parse.com to MongoDB. We are looking for  example which runs TI CC3200 platform and can push and retreat data to/from MongoDB.

Originally parse.com provided this example and in fact it still available for free download from Parse.com

We are really appreciate any help here, also we are hoping parse.com team can share some thoughts on this topic.

Regards,

Stalker